# How to handle a dashed border line that becomes solid because it is shared

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography

I am using Arc 10.3.1 and I am having a cartographic dilemma.  As shown in the picture below, I have dashed line representing borders of various city zones.  Where these border lines share borders with other polygons the resulting dashed line becomes much thicker and in some cases a completely solid line.  I can handle a slight variation in the size of the dashes but a solid line is unacceptable to me.

I have tinkered with changing the outline size and the outline dash type but each time when I export the lines are still merged. I have used definition queries to exclude the polygons in the middle, allowing the outer polygons lines to form the border for the interior ones, but there are several that I can not exclude because they create an outside border on the map that must be shown.

Is there a method to fix this little issue of mine?

[image]

Comment: Do you have  Standard or Advanced license?  If so you can try representations.  If not or it may take just as much time to split up the boundary to individual lines and assign each segment a "symbology" attribute.

Comment: Advanced, do you know of a tutorial about what you are referring.  I have not heard of representations before.

Comment: Convert polygons to lines

Comment: ahh I gotcha, I was a little confused.  Yeah that would work just hoping there was a cartographic trick that I could use without doing too much extra work  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to ArcToolbox > Cartographic Refinement > Set Representation Control Point At Intersect tool, and run the function on your feature data (after you created a representation for it.) 
The tool aligns the hash boundary symbology so that when it overlaps it does not look like a solid line.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add, that you can add a representation to your feature by going to ArcToolbox > Representation Management > Add Representation.